# Define a variable for linker in a Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker-scripts

I use for gcc for compiling.
In the ldscript, I have such a definition :

```
STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(STACK_SIZE) ? STACK_SIZE : DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x1000;
```

I would like to define STACK_SIZEvariablz in a Makefile
How should I proceed ?
I ve tried this :

```
STACK_SIZE=0
LDFLAGS = -DSTACK_SIZE=${STACK_SIZE}
```

But it does not work.

Second question, how can I display a variable in the LD script to get the value on the console output, like in a makefile :

```
$(info $$USEMODULE is [${USEMODULE}])
```

Thanks

Comment: try `$(STACK_SIZE)`, and something like `$(info USEMODULE = $(USEMODULE))`

Comment: These are all linker questions, not makefile questions: I recommend you first figure out how to do these things from the shell prompt.  Once you know how to do that, putting it into a makefile is straightforward.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference in Make between `$(X)` and `${X}`. What do you mean when you say that your code "does not work"?

Comment: When I say it doesn't not work I mean when I define a variable in the Makefile It has no effect  in the ldScript. The variable in the ldsrcipt still have 0x1000 as value.

Comment: I found out a solution in Makefile:
<pre> <code> export LDFLAGS += -Wl,--defsym=STACK_SIZE=0x1000  <pre> <code>